# What is a LB score in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, accuracy

I was going through an [article](http://blog.kaggle.com/2015/11/09/profiling-top-kagglers-gilberto-titericz-new-1-in-the-world/) on kaggle blogs. Repeatedly, the author mentions 'LB score' and 'LB fit') as a metric for effectiveness of machine learning (along with cross validation (CV) score).

With a research for the meaning of 'LB' I spent quite a bit of time, I realised that generally people directly refer it as LB without much background.

So my question is - What is a 'LB'?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In the context of Kaggle, it means **L**eader**B**oard (emphasis mine).

Comment: thanks. it seems it's just applicable for the kaggle competitions.

Comment: Correct. Unimportant.

Comment: Worth adding that the score is *usually* just some standard metric such as log loss, and the focus on the LB score in discussion about Kaggle is around the use (and potential for over-use) of a long running public test set.

Comment: The question is what it is - spelling out the abbreviation is not saying much about what it is. I am surprised 22 people have upvoted it !

Comment: It's what it sounds like: [a rankings table](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/leaderboard).

Comment: @NeilSlater Does this LB score have anything to do with evaluation metrics (say classification eval. metrics)? Or can it be translated to them?

Comment: @RFNO Often the LB score on a Kaggle competition *is* a standard classification metric. You cannot easily translate between metrics, although usually a good score on one metric will correlate well with a good score on another.